# Convergence of the Ito integral along a filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion, and $\mathcal F_t$ its natural filtration. Let $X$ be an $\mathcal F_t$-predictable process.

**Question:** Fix $b > a > 0$. Is it true that for all sequences $t_n \downarrow 0$ of positive numbers, we have

$$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \int_{a}^b \mathbb E[X_s| \mathcal F_{s-t_n}] \ dW_s = \int_{a}^b X_s dW_s$$

almost surely?

Comment: For each $t > 0$ the left-hand side is only defined almost surely, so for every $\epsilon > 0$ the exceptional sets for $t \in (0, \epsilon)$ can well add up to all of $\Omega$. For this reason, it is not clear to me how one should understand almost sure convergence.

Comment: Ah, this is true. I will have to use a slightly weaker formulation.

Comment: By the way, for each $t > 0$, it is also the case that for each $s > 0$, $\mathbb E[X_s| \mathcal F_{s-t}]$ is only defined almost surely right? Does this present a problem, or is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Hm I suppose it would still be defined $d\mathbb P \times d\mu$ almost everywhere, so this would not be an issue.

Comment: I do not have a proof off the top of my head, but yes, what you write in your last comment sounds reasonable.

Comment: Comment: Suppose $\int_a^b\mathsf{E}[X_s^2]ds<\infty$, then it is easy to get
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}\Big[\int_{a}^{b}\mathsf{E}[X_s|
 \mathscr{F}_{s-t_n}]\,\mathrm{d}W_s-\int_a^b X_s\,\mathrm{d}W_s\Big]^2=0.
\end{equation*}
But, it is difficult to prove the convergence of Ito integrals is almost surely, because even for a non-stochastic integrand,  there 
are no ready-made results on a.s. convergence of Ito integrals.